# Find Recurrence Relation from Code Snippet

Tags: python, recursion, asymptotic-complexity, recurrence

I know some basic rules to create Recurrence Relation from code like this;

```
if n=0 return 1
else return F(n-1)*n
```

The Recurrence Relation of this code is `F(n)=F(n-1)*n for n>0` But I have a more complex code snippet to solve and create its Recurrence Relation below.

[image]

There are two paramethers in the function and how to describe them in equation?
Is there any way or source that can guide me through this?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you're allowed to use two variables in a function description.  Note here that your parameters are *sequences*, not scalars.

Your left-hand side will be something like

```
F(A, B) = ...
```

Now note that

```
i = |A|
j = |B|
```

I don't know what notation you use for a sub-list.  In case it helps, I believe that the function computes how many values match between the two arrays.  If the arrays are sorted, it will be relatively fast, too.

Is this enough to get you going?

As for the final question, StackOverflow is not a primary source for off-site resources (see [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) item #4).  What did you find or not find when you searched for such references?